# How to calculate data sent and received by an Ionic3/Angular4 app?

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4

As an addition to synchro process in Ionic3 app, I need to calculate data sent and received by the app. I've discovered on the Web that Ionic3 does not offer a dedicated plugin to serve that. The suggested solution is calculate the content of template and attachments. How would that work?

Comment: Hope this link will help you: https://codeburst.io/using-google-analytics-with-angular-25c93bffaa18

Comment: Thanks I will follow that trace. Let know if succeeded

Comment: Thanks once more; that was a partially good trace. GA is a fantastic tool for monitoring purposes. What I need is to measure inside the app and then log those data in database. GA is only a receiver, a kind of monitor. I can not grab data from there. Still looking for answer...

Comment: I've edited your question for grammar.   I also removed your thanks because that is not needed here.